# Displaying data from database in Jtable error

Tags: mysql, jtable

Im trying to display a set of data which is in my database into a Jtable.

This is my code

```
ResultSet rs = dbConnection.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM taxdata");
      ArrayList<Tax> taxinfo = new ArrayList();

      while (rs.next()) {              
          Tax taxdetails = new Tax(rs.getString(1),rs.getDouble(2), rs.getDouble(3));
          taxinfo.add(taxdetails);
      }
      return taxinfo;
```

This is the display method:

```
public void showDetails(){
    DefaultTableModel mdl = (DefaultTableModel) taxDetails.getModel();
    mdl.setRowCount(0);
    try {
        ArrayList<Tax> taxset = taxdao.getTaxDetails();
        for (Tax tax : taxset) {
            mdl.addRow(new Object[] {tax.getPro_type() , tax.getSaleTax() , tax.getImportTax()});
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

I have a model for tax which is: ( I didnt show the getters and setters)

```
public Tax(String product_type , double sales_tax , double import_tax){
    this.importTax = import_tax;
    this.pro_type = product_type;
    this.saleTax = sales_tax;
}
```

This is my tax table in database and this is the way i want it to be displayed in my program:

[image]

But it displays like this :

[image]

If someone could point me out the mistake it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code is fine. Please check you database connection or db. You can print the `taxinfo` ArrayList and check whether you are receiving correct data.

Comment: Found the error. Getters and setters were static. Thanks for the concern :)